# How to create div element on page load in JavaScript using createElement function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dynamic-programming, onload

I want to create a div element on page load event but my script is not working as expected.

```
function createfn(){
    //debugger;
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    var para = document.createTextNode('The man who mistook his wife for a hat');
    element.appendChild(para);
    document.getElementByTagName(body).appendChild(element);
    
}
window.onload=createfn();
```

What is it wrong with this code?

Comment: this is native js - why the tag for jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a few issues:

first the tag name `body` needs to be wrapped in quotes. in your code you are passing an undeclared variable called body.

Secondly, its `getElementsByTagName()` asthis function returns multiple elements in an array.

Lastly, you need to target the first body element:

```
    function createfn(){
    //debugger;
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    var para = document.createTextNode('The man who mistook his wife for a hat');
    element.appendChild(para);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(element);

    }
    window.onload=createfn();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzwjwcxf/)

Comment: Good. I got it. how to set id for that div element in javascript?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("id", "yourIdHere");